# Database Design for storing Key-Value Tags per Item

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, tags, key-value

I want to build an online shop where the products don't follow a specific schema, so the attributes can be quite different for each product.
My idea is to allow the sellers to define custom tags with values (like key-value pairs) for their products, which I can analyze later to provide the most used tags per product category as filters.
I read a lot about this topic online, but in most cases, only simple tags (without values) are discussed. In this case, I would just store the tags as JSON in an additional field in my postgres database.
But I'm not sure if that's the best solution with my key-value pairs. For example, the key for a product could be something like "weight", and I want to provide filters for it, like "weight" > 100 AND "weight" < 1000.

I'm trying to find answers to the following questions:

- What would be the best data structure for my case?
- How can I handle data types? One seller could type "1000" for the weight, another one could type "1000kg" or "1 ton". I'm not sure how I can handle this while filtering.
- Are there any real-life examples for a scenario like this? Amazon does not provide that much filters, and most other shops are designed for one specific type of product and do not face this problem.

Comment: A table with `product_id, key, value` columns…?! If you want to deduplicate tags, then a table with `id, key, value`, and another many-to-many table with `product_id, tag_id`…?! — And if you want to be able to query `1000`, `1000kg` and `1 ton` equally, you'll need to apply some normalisation in your application first and store just `1000`.

Comment: @deceze That's the dreaded "entity-attribute-value" design. It is about the worst imaginable design for a relational database.

Comment: JSON is fine for this purpose, but you can't have GIN index support for queries with `>`. You'd need to create a custom b-tree index.

Comment: Mongo or similar database would be better than a relational DB here since your attributes vary so much.  For your second question, the application that imports data into the db should force data types and units.

Comment: If you want to use a relational database, I would create a table for products. In this table I define general attributes for a product: name, price, etc. And n tables for each category of a product, with specific attributes for the category (you can define specific indexes for each category) . If you want to provide the ability to add other attributes, you can define additional field in JSON type, but without searching by the field.